# Filter out nan rows in a specific column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

```
df =

Col1 Col2 Col3
1    nan  4
2    5    4
3    3    nan
```

Given the dataframe `df`, I want to obtain a new dataframe `df2` that does not contain `nan` in the column `Col2`. This is the expected result:
    df2 =

```
Col1 Col2 Col3
2    5    4
3    3    nan
```

I know that it's possible to use `pandas.isnull` and `dropna`, however how to specify only particular column to which filtering should be applied?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

you can use [`DataFrame.dropna()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) method:

```
In [202]: df.dropna(subset=['Col2'])
Out[202]:
   Col1  Col2  Col3
1     2   5.0   4.0
2     3   3.0   NaN
```

or (in this case) less idiomatic [Series.notnull()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.notnull.html):

```
In [204]: df.loc[df.Col2.notnull()]
Out[204]:
   Col1  Col2  Col3
1     2   5.0   4.0
2     3   3.0   NaN
```

or using [DataFrame.query()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) method:

```
In [205]: df.query("Col2 == Col2")
Out[205]:
   Col1  Col2  Col3
1     2   5.0   4.0
2     3   3.0   NaN
```

`numexpr` solution:

```
In [241]: import numexpr as ne

In [242]: col = df.Col2

In [243]: df[ne.evaluate("col == col")]
Out[243]:
   Col1  Col2  Col3
1     2   5.0   4.0
2     3   3.0   NaN
```

Answer (score 15):

Use [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```
df = df.dropna(subset=['Col2'])
print (df)
  Col1  Col2  Col3
1     2   5.0   4.0
2     3   3.0   NaN
```

Another solution - [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`notnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.notnull.html):

```
df = df[df['Col2'].notnull()]
print (df)
   Col1  Col2  Col3
1     2   5.0   4.0
2     3   3.0   NaN
```

What is same as:

```
df = df[~df['Col2'].isnull()]
print (df)
   Col1  Col2  Col3
1     2   5.0   4.0
2     3   3.0   NaN
```

Answer (score 6):

Using `numpy`'s `isnan` to mask and construct a new dataframe

```
m = ~np.isnan(df.Col2.values)
pd.DataFrame(df.values[m], df.index[m], df.columns)

   Col1  Col2  Col3
1   2.0   5.0   4.0
2   3.0   3.0   NaN
```

---

***Timing***
*Bigger Data*

```
np.random.seed([3,1415])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([np.nan, 1], size=(10000, 10))).add_prefix('Col')

%%timeit
m = ~np.isnan(df.Col2.values)
pd.DataFrame(df.values[m], df.index[m], df.columns)
1000 loops, best of 3: 326 µs per loop

%timeit df.query("Col2 == Col2")
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.48 ms per loop

%timeit df.loc[df.Col2.notnull()]
1000 loops, best of 3: 417 µs per loop

%timeit df[~df['Col2'].isnull()]
1000 loops, best of 3: 385 µs per loop

%timeit df.dropna(subset=['Col2'])
1000 loops, best of 3: 913 µs per loop
```

Comment: Could you please add timing for this solution: `import numexpr as ne; col = df.Col2.values; %timeit df[ne.evaluate("col == col")]`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count and graph the number of nan's before dropping your column(s)

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

cols = df.columns
nans = [df[col].isna().sum() for col in cols] 

sns.set(font_scale=1.1)
ax = sns.barplot(cols, nans, palette='hls', log=False)
ax.set(xlabel='Feature', ylabel='Number of NaNs', title='Number of NaNs per feature')
for p, uniq in zip(ax.patches, nans):
    height = p.get_height()
    ax.text(p.get_x()+p.get_width()/2.,
            height + 10,
            uniq,
            ha="center") 
ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticklabels(),rotation=90)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple implementation below follows on from the above - but shows filtering out *nan* rows in a specific column - **in place** - and for **large** data frames **count rows with *nan* by column name** (before and after)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,np.nan,'A100'],[4,5,'A213'],[7,8,np.nan],[10,np.nan,'GA23']])
df.columns = ['areaCode','Distance','accountCode']
```

dataframe

```
areaCode    Distance    accountCode
1           NaN         A100
4           5.0         A213
7           8.0         NaN
10          NaN         GA23
```

**Before**: count rows with nan (for each column):

```
df.isnull().sum()
```

count by column:

```
areaCode       0
Distance       2
accountCode    1
dtype: int64
```

remove unwanted rows in-place:

```
df.dropna(subset=['Distance'],inplace=True)
```

**After**: count rows with nan (for each column):

```
df.isnull().sum()
```

count by column:

```
areaCode       0
Distance       0
accountCode    1
dtype: int64
```

dataframe:

```
areaCode    Distance    accountCode
4           5.0         A213
7           8.0         NaN
```